# How to play sound in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, ios6

I have found so many solutions here on stackoverflow, but for some reason all of them failed to produce any sound what so ever.

Here is my current code:

```
PRE: I've added AudioToolbox.framework and imported <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> in my .m file


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL* sndurl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"aif"];
    SystemSoundID snd;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)sndurl, &snd);
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(snd, nil, nil, SoundFinished, nil);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(snd);
}

void SoundFinished (SystemSoundID snd, void* context) {
        AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(snd);
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(snd);
}
```

This solution is straight out of book. But when I run the project, if fails to produce any sound. My file is test.aif, which is 5 seconds long.

Any suggestions why it's not working? If that's not the best solution, how do you produce a sound on iOS6?

Comment: Make sure the hardware mute switch is off. Systems sounds are turned off in silent mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201141/play-a-wav-with-audio-toolbox) and others, playing an audio clip can be as simple as the following, my using a method (function).  I've done it before myself.

```
- (void)playAudio {
    [self playSound:@"pageflip1" :@"wav"];
}

- (void)playSound :(NSString *)fName :(NSString *) ext{
    SystemSoundID audioEffect;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : fName ofType :ext];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath : path]) {
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns '(null)' for the path variable. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Drag and drop your audio file into the project sidebar.

Comment: THANKS! I figured the "Add to targets" checkbox was not selected when I added files. It SHOULD be selected.

Comment: Do no play sounds with this method. System sounds do not obey the volume that the user has set. If you use system sounds, the user cannot control the volume with the volume switch. Use the `AVAudioPlayer` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to try testing it on an actual device because the simulator can have problems when using AVFoundation.